# Confusing error in Rails Mailer test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to test my user mailer, and I've written out `user_mailer_test.rb` like so:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:test)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

When I run my test suite, it throws an error:

```
ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 2015-12-01 16:35:46 +0000]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (1448987746.26s)
SyntaxError:         SyntaxError: (erb):36: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
        ...ut.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
```

What `end` am I missing? The test looks properly enclosed to me. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I just ran my entire test suite, rather than the mailer test alone, and they are *all* throwing `unexpected end-of-input` despite the fact that they all ran fine an hour ago and I have not edited them recently. Is this a problem with Cloud9 and not my code, maybe?

Comment: Isn't the error in your mail template? It says `erb` in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing that all of my tests were failing, I realized that the error was in my user fixtures. I added the `<% end %>` tag back on, reset and re-seeded, and all my tests passed. Strange, though, that the test doesn't know to indicate the problem was in my `users.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing end tag in your erb file.

Comment: I just ran my entire test suite, rather than the mailer test alone, and they are all throwing unexpected end-of-input despite the fact that they all ran fine an hour ago and I have not edited them recently. Is this a problem with Cloud9 and not my code, maybe?